# Auto screen rotation in windows 7 mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile-phones

We have developed a application for HTC HD2 mobile, which has windows 7 CE. 
I have designed application to work for both the orientation (portrait, landscape) 
         Now I wanted to achieve auto screen rotation (portrait to landscape and landscape to portrait) according to the device movement (some thing like iPhone).
         Can i able to achieve it? if yes how can I? It will be appreciable if you provide me link or sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation site has some information on how to access it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.accelerometersensor_members(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [2 way limitations of the accelerometer on the HD2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMts1TyBkjs).

There is some info [here](http://blog.enterprisemobile.com/2008/07/using-htc-diamonds-sensor-sdk-from-managed-code/) about using the accelerometer from the managed code.